# React Native: How to integrate Stripe?

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments, reactjs, stripe-connect

Did some research and it seems React Native doesn’t support Stripe well. Seen ttps://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-stripe-api and https://github.com/lrettig/react-native-stripe , but the former is outdated, not supporting Stripe Connect, and latter is only iOS supported.

So the only straight forward integration I came across were: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/11/03/using-stripe-api-in-react-native-with-fetch.html and https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfKg5GYGxq2XfQ3ebHx-b2A

Question is: are http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/11/03/using-stripe-api-in-react-native-with-fetch.html and https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfKg5GYGxq2XfQ3ebHx-b2A both fully PCI-compliant?

Here it lays out what's needed to be fully PCI-compliant, https://stripe.com/docs/security

If anyone who has already fully integrated Stripe using React Native can chime in, would really appreciate any insight or guidance.

Thank you in advance and will be sure to upvote/accept answer

Comment: Perhaps [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-express-stripe-payment/) helps, even though it is React and not React Native. But I think you could substitute React with React Native and the infrastructure around it would stay the same.